# Remove groups from Member of tab from user properties

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell Below scripts i have which remove all groups from the user member of tab except "Domain users" this works fine many time without any issues

## Removing Groups from User

```
$list = Import-Csv c:\user\DN.csv
foreach ($entry in $list)
$UserDN = $entry.DistinguishedName
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$UserDN)" | foreach-object {
if ($_.name -ne "Domain Users") {remove-adgroupmember -identity $_.name -member   $UserDN -Confirm:$False}
```

But the problem is when if this script is not able to remove any group from user member of tab it throws an error below but it doesn't shows from which user id it was unable to remove the membership as the user distinguished name is imported from a CSV file.

```
Remove-ADGroupMember : The specified account name is not a member of the group
At C:\User\removegroups.ps1:35 char:115
+ Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$UserDN)" | foreach-object {if ($_.name -ne "Domain    Users") {remove-adgroupmember <<
<<  -identity $_.name -member $UserDN -Confirm:$False}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (xyz:ADGroup) [Remove-ADGroupMember],     ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified account name is not a member of the     group,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = Import-Csv c:\user\DN.csv
foreach ($entry in $list)
$UserDN = $entry.DistinguishedName
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$UserDN)" | foreach-object {
if ($_.name -ne "Domain Users") {
try {
remove-adgroupmember -identity $_.name -member $UserDN -Confirm:$False} }
catch [ADexcption] {
write-output "Error Deleting User:" $_.name
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried a lot but this is not working shows below error The Try statement is missing its Catch or Finally block.
Can you please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Csv DN.csv | foreach {
$user = Get-ADUser $_.username
$UserDN = $user.DistinguishedName
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$UserDN)" | foreach-object {
    if ($_.name -ne "Domain Users") {
        try {
            remove-adgroupmember -identity $_.name -member $UserDN -Confirm:$False
        }
        catch [ADexcption] {
            write-output "Error Deleting User:" $_.name
        }
    }
}}
```